# Classification of Cones

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry

I am attempting to classify (convex rational) cones in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

We say here that $\sigma\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ is a **cone** if there exist $u,v\in\Bbb{Z}^2$ which $\Bbb{R}$-span the whole plane $\Bbb{R}^2$ and
$$ \sigma=\mathop{Cone}(u,v)=\{tu+sv: \ t,s\in \Bbb{R}_{\geq0}\}$$
We can here wlog assume that $u$ lies on the positive $x$-axis and $v$ on the upper half-plane.

We say that two cones $\sigma,\sigma'$ are **isomorphic** if there exists a group isomorphism
$$A\colon \Bbb{Z}^2\longrightarrow\Bbb{Z}^2$$
(hence $\det A=\pm1$) such that $A(\sigma)=\sigma'$. Now classification takes the following form

> **Claim:** any cone $\sigma$ as above is isomorphic to 
>   $$\sigma'=\mathop{Cone}\{(1,0), (q,p)\}$$
>   where $p,q\in\Bbb{N}$ are relatively prime and either $p=q=1$ or $1\leq q<p$. Moreover $p,q$ are uniquely determined.

any hint for attacking this? thanks

Comment: Are the $t$ and $s$ that parametrize the points in a cone assumed to be integers or reals?

Comment: Dear @SammyBlack, they are real. And you made me notice a typo. Thank you. Let me edit.

Comment: Could you clarify this “group isomorphism” part? What group are you referring to? If it is the additive group of vectors, I don't see the argument about the determinant, since scaling everything by 2 is an isomorphism there.